# How to create a Trac report containing all tickets a user has touched or is responsible for?

Tags: sql, report, trac

There are numerous examples for the creation of [TracReports](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports). [This](http://groups.google.com/group/trac-users/t/acefc2830b78df49) is still a tricky one, not covered by any existing recipe, that I'm aware of:

> ... designing a report to show all tickets where the user is the
>   owner, reporter, or tickets they have not created but tickets they
>   have left a comment on. It's the last part that's tricky.

Any pointers, considering effectiveness as an added bonus?

Comment: What SQL flavor are you using?  SQLite?

Comment: SQLite here, yes. But I try to follow Trac philosophy of using most portable, least db backend-specific SQL statements. Do you see a specific problem with that?

Comment: I was getting errors in the final "ORDER BY" clause when testing on my system (MySQL-based), so I figured I'd double-check just to be sure.  I had to replace column names with their aliases (e.g.: `t.milestone` --> `__group__`) to make it work.  I'm testing commands directly to the DB and not going through the Trac reports UI, so that might be the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first own working solution:

**"(current) user is owner or reporter or (one of) comment authors"**

```
SELECT
  p.value AS __color__,
  t.milestone AS __group__,
  id AS ticket, t.type AS type,
  reporter, t.time as created,
  owner, changetime AS modified,
  author as commenter, tcg.time as date
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
LEFT JOIN ticket_change tcg ON t.id = tcg.ticket
WHERE owner = $USER OR reporter = $USER
GROUP BY id

UNION

SELECT
  p.value AS __color__,
  t.milestone AS __group__,
  id AS ticket, t.type AS type,
  reporter, t.time as created,
  owner, changetime AS modified,
  author as commenter, tcg.time as date
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
LEFT JOIN ticket_change tcg ON t.id = tcg.ticket
WHERE author = $USER
  AND id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM ticket
  WHERE owner = $USER OR reporter = $USER
)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY t.milestone, p.value, t.type, t.time
```

I'm no SQL guru by no means, so there's likely a more effective solution, but this one works at least in showing commented tickets and still each ticket not more than once.

Comment: One potential issue is that this query returns all tickets that a user has *modified*, not just tickets where they have left a comment.  For example, on my system this picked up a ticket where all the user did was add himself to the 'CC' list.  To resolve this you'd need to filter out user comments from Trac's auto-generated comment text, but I don't know if that's possible using SQL alone.

Comment: Trac 1.0 looks like it has a "Comments Only" option on the ticket view that filters out ticket property changes and only shows real comments.  This feature may be able to be used here, but I don't know if it's something that can be done using only SQL (you may have to wrap it in a plugin).